# Read xz files in go

Tags: go, xz

How can I read [xz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xz) files in a go program? When I try to read them using [`lzma`](https://code.google.com/p/lzma/), I get an `error in lzma header` error.

Comment: I'm guessing that this library only supports LZMA and not LZMA2 which is used by `xz` archives.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have 3 options.

1. Try another library, perhaps one that uses cgo. I see two [here](http://godoc.org/?q=xz).
2. Use cgo directly/make your own lib.
3. Use the xz executable.

Option three is easier than it sounds. Here is what I would use:

```
func xzReader(r io.Reader) io.ReadCloser {
    rpipe, wpipe := io.Pipe()

    cmd := exec.Command("xz", "--decompress", "--stdout")
    cmd.Stdin = r
    cmd.Stdout = wpipe

    go func() {
        err := cmd.Run()
        wpipe.CloseWithError(err)
    }()

    return rpipe
}
```

Runnable code here: http://play.golang.org/p/SrgZiKdv9a

Comment: Thanks, I somehow missed both godoc.org and this marvelously simple piping.

Comment: Your Option 3 solution is generally useful for a wide range of shell commands to be incorporated into Go programs.

Answer (score 2):

I recently created an XZ decompression package. It does not require Cgo. You can find it here:

https://github.com/xi2/xz

A program to decompress stdin to stdout:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/xi2/xz"
)

func main() {
    r, err := xz.NewReader(os.Stdin, 0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    _, err = io.Copy(os.Stdout, r)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```